# Automated Firebase tests in Java, using email login

Tags: java, authentication, firebase

I would like to write some automated end-to-end tests for my Firebase application.
The app has a mobile client, a web client and a server, all connected to Firebase.

I want to test the server logic so I want to write some test clients that first perform a login operation and then use the AuthID on subsequent requests.

The server is in Java, so, ideally I would like to write the tests in Java. I have a simple  auth function:

```
public void auth() throws InterruptedException {
    final CountDownLatch cd = new CountDownLatch(1);
    firebaseRef.authWithPassword(user, password,                  
        new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
                System.out.println("Auth successful " + authData);
                cd.countDown();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                System.out.println("Authentication failed " + firebaseError);
                cd.countDown();
            }
        });
    cd.await();
}
```

However, when running the test I get the following error message:

`Authentication failed FirebaseError: There was an exception while connecting to the authentication server: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure`

Email & password authentication is enabled on the Firebase and the user email+password combination is correctly set in the test and matches the one in Firebase. I have verified these work as expected from the web interface of my application.

If I follow the call trace, internally in the Firebase code base it throws a NPE:

`Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.firebase.client.Firebase.toString()`

Questions:

1. Is this type of authentication supported by Firebase from Java (not Android)?
2. If so, do you have *any pointers* on how to figure out what is wrong, (since the error message itself doesn't tell me much)?
3. If not, what would be the best way to set up some automated tests as described above?

Comment: This seems to answer Q1: "The Firebase Java SDK supports both Android and plain Java, however the Firebase Simple Login library currently only supports Android" See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25195190/get-firebase-to-work-with-java-not-android

Comment: Thanks, but I think that answer may be outdated. According to the [docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html) Simple Login has been merged into core. Also, I don't get any Android related stack trace, so I have some hope that it's not exclusively for Android :))

Comment: Firebase login is designed to work on Android and with plain Java. It seems our fix with regard to the POODLE vulnerability seems to cause some hiccups on some Java implementations. We're working on resolving the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I seem to remember my approach used to work a few weeks ago, could this be the problem?

Comment: We resolved the issue, the test should work fine now. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Great, if you make it an answer I'll accept. Congrats on joining Google :))