# Trying to start a Firebase Java client

Tags: java, firebase

I am trying to start a Java client from scratch, and have pulled in `firebase-client-jvm:2.2.1` in gradle.  I get the following in a stack trace while trying to compile anything that includes the `com.firebase.client.Firebase` class:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class com.firebase.client.Firebase due to missing dependency android/content/Context
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.convertUncaughtExceptionToCompilationError(CompilationUnit.java:1083)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class com.firebase.client.Firebase due to missing dependency android/content/Context
```

I have no desire to include anything to do with Android, and all of the answers I find state that firebase "supports both" (i.e. [Get Firebase to work with java, not Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25195190/get-firebase-to-work-with-java-not-android?lq=1)), but I do not know how to get going.

I cannot find examples or tutorials online showing a "simple" Java-only client, and would appreciate any "getting started" help.

UPDATE: Not only did I have to create the `android.context.Context` class, I had to give up on writing the program in Groovy.  When I switched it back to a Java project it seemed to smooth things out considerably.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known bug of the Firebase library with dynamic languages on the JVM. There is an easy workaround: Create an empty dummy class `Context` in the package `android.content`. The class is not used at runtime, however the class loader expects it to be present.

See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/XLbpLpqCdDI/ncuw32Xr-4YJ

Comment: you mean i have to create this package in my own project and put empty class called Context?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Grails application, you need to make it a Java class (i.e. `src/main/java`).  If you put it in `src/main/groovy`, the problem still exists.